# in VHDL, how to check if file exists before opening it?

Tags: vhdl

In Verilog, I can check if a file exists by opening the file and then checking if the file descriptor is zero, and if it is not to assume the file doesn't exist.  For example, as follows:

```
    module testbench;

    function file_exists;
        input [80*8:0] filename;        
        integer        file;
        integer        error;
    begin
        file = $fopen(filename, "r");
        if (!file) begin
           $display("\nFile Open Failed with Error Code = %x", error); 
           file_exists = 0;
        end
        else begin
           $fclose(file);
           file_exists = 1;
        end
    end
    endfunction

    integer x;
    initial begin
       x = file_exists("sdfsdf.txt");
       $display("x: %0b", x);          
    end

    endmodule
```

How can I do the same thing in vhdl?

Comment: In no language should you ever check if a file exists before opening it.  You attempt to open it.  If your attempt fails, you check the reason for failure, and if the failure was caused by non-existence then you know it didn't exist at the time you tried to open it.

Comment: TCL can check that a file exists before opening it, and Im sure many others can.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.5.2 File operations "In the second form of FILE_OPEN, the value returned through the Status parameter indicates the results of the procedure call:"..."A value of NAME_ERROR indicates that the external file does not exist (in the case of an attempt to read from the external file)"... .

Comment: VHDL-2019 will add a `dir_ItemExists(...)` procedure for this purpose. See http://www.eda-twiki.org/cgi-bin/view.cgi/P1076/LCS2016_006c for details.

Answer (score 6):

When you open a file, for example:

```
file_open(status, file_handle, “my_file.txt”, read_mode);
```

You get a status of type `file_open_status`. It can have a number of values: `open_ok`, `status_error`, `name_error` and `mode_error`. You'll get `name_error` if the file isn't found

Answer (score 2):

```
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use std.textio.all;          

entity testebench is 
end entity;

architecture sim of testbench is 

    impure function file_exists(
        filename : in string
    ) return boolean is
        variable open_status :FILE_OPEN_STATUS;
        file     infile      :text;
    begin
        file_open(open_status, infile, filename, read_mode);
        if open_status /= open_ok then
            return false;
        else
            file_close(infile);
            return true;
        end if;
    end function;

begin

    process
        f1 :boolean;
    begin
        f1 = file_exists("fgsfgsdfg.txt")
        report "found: " & boolean'image(f1);
    end process;

end architecture;
```